# JSP ParseInt Error Return Value

Tags: jsp, parsing, special-characters

```
// bbs
String saveFolder = "/upload/";
String realFolder = application.getRealPath(saveFolder);

// error
if (realFolder.substring(realFolder.length()-1, realFolder.length()) != "\\") {
    realFolder += "/";
}

String encType = "UTF-8";
int sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

try {
    MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request, realFolder, sizeLimit, encType, new DefaultFileRenamePolicy());
    Enumeration files = multipartRequest.getFileNames();
    File oldFile, newFile, newDir;

    String bbsTitle = multipartRequest.getParameter("bbsTitle");
    String bbsContent = multipartRequest.getParameter("bbsContent");

    //parseInt 오류
    int bbsID = 0;
    if (multipartRequest.getParameter("bbsID") != null) {
        //bbsID = Integer.parseInt(multipartRequest.getParameter("bbsID"));
        bbsID = Integer.parseInt(multipartRequest.getParameter("bbsID").trim());
    }
```

multipartRequest.getParameter("bbsID") = 1
but Integer.parseInt(multipartRequest.getParameter("bbsID")) =

Help me...

Comment: what is error and stack trace?

Comment: Nothing errors.